# Map View is not loading in android 11

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-11

I'm trying to load a map in my fragment, but when i go to that screen it shows me a blank screen with logo at the left bottom, but when keyboard appear the map also appear. (SS attached), this issue is just in android 11

[Picture When i go to map screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJGIH.png)

[Picture When Keyboard open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xy48t.png)

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in Logcat?

Comment: @ecg8 no error in logcat

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the relevant code/layout files to help answerers?

Answer (score 0):

It was because of

> android:animateLayoutChanges="true"

in my frame layout